# Regarding gravity force during circular motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, centripetal-force, string

If I spin a ball attached to a string so that the string is pointing diagonally upwards, the centripetal force would be:

$$T \cos\theta,$$

where $\theta$ is the angle between the horizontal and the string, and $T$ is the tension. Then the vertical force would be: 
$$T \sin\theta + mg.$$

Given that the ball spins in a horizontal circle, how does it deal with an unbalanced vertical force and not fall downwards?

Comment: Are you certain that is the centripetal force?

Comment: If your ball is spinning in a horizontal plane, the string will make an angle to the horizontal.

Answer (score 1):

You should really start with the constraint $T \sin \theta = mg$. You know that the vertical forces have to be balanced! Then you can express $T$ as $T = \frac{mg}{\sin \theta}$.

And since the centripetal force is $F_c = T \sin \theta$, you can then say $F_c = mg \frac{\cos \theta}{\sin \theta} = mg \cot \theta$.

You can check that this makes sense! If $\theta = 90$, then the ball is at rest and there should be no centripetal force. Indeed $\cot 90 = 0$ so $F_c = 0$.

If $\theta = 0$, then the ball is completely horizontal. That's actually impossible, and you can see $\cot 90 \to \infty$, so the force would have to be infinite.

Answer (score 0):

It does fall downward, a cycle with the angle $\theta$ maintained all the way around is not achievable.

If, however, it falls to $-\theta$ at an azimuth of $180^o$, (neglecting losses due to air resistance/friction and so on) it accelerates enough during that fall to return to $+\theta$ at an azimuth of $0^o$

Answer (score 0):

This diagram should help:

[image]

The force of gravity is countered by the vertical component of the tension in the string, $T\sin\theta$; the centripetal force is provided by the horizontal components, $T\cos\theta$.

The string cannot be horizontal on a stable orbit with gravity.

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake.
If you define the positive forces to up, rhen the gravity is negative.

$$T\sin\theta - mg=0$$
Or if you define the positive forces to down,
$$-T\sin\theta + mg=0$$

Anyway,
$$T\sin\theta = mg$$

Which means that the forces are in opposite directions. 
So, the force is not unbalanced force in the vertical direction.

Comment: I believe you meant to write “$T sin \theta$”?

Comment: Why you say that?

Comment: Because $T cos \theta$ is the component of the tension perpendicular to the gravitational force, whereas $T sin \theta$ is the component parallel (and opposite in direction) to the gravitational force.

Comment: Ohh, yes. You're right. I was thinking in a different angle.